# What is the adiabatic temperature gradient of ice?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, adiabatic, ice

What is the adiabatic temperature gradient of ice at Earth's surface conditions?

The [adiabatic temperature gradient](https://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Adiabatic_temperature_gradient) is a non-conductive spatial temperature difference caused by acceleration on thermal motion. In gases this is also called [lapse rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapse_rate).

Comment: Gases move vertically in the atmosphere and the pressure changes are sufficient to do work on the gas.  I can't think of where on the earth ice moves in a way that causes adiabatic work to be done on the ice.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I mentioned thermal motion in the question. Thermal motion is on the atom or molecule level. There is thermal motion even in non moving gas, and thus a lapse rate. In liquids and solids there are also thermal motions affected by gravity. Ice can of course be compressed non isotropically. Otherwise temperature change due to isotropic adiabatic pressurization of ice would give the answer. Should I ask a new question about that?

Comment: You get a lapse rate in air because for rapid motion, the adiabatic work dominates over regular thermal equilibration.  If the motion is too slow, then the thermal equilibration dominates and there is no lapse.    Gas in a tall cylinder that is not moving does not have a lapse rate.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Do you mean that the thermal motion of gas in a tall cylinder is not affected by gravity? That can not be the case. Gas is also by definition moving on the molecular or atomic scale.

Comment: No, I'm only talking about the case where there is no convective motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we s-l-o-w-l-y rotate a contained length of material upright, we'll generally see a depth-dependent, hydrostatic stress state arise from self-compression:

$$\frac{dP}{dz}=\rho g,$$

with pressure $P$, depth $z$, density $\rho$, and gravity field $g$, and heat exchange during this slow process will maintain a constant temperature T, so the resulting temperature gradient will be zero during and after this **isothermal** process:

$$\left(\frac{dT}{dz}\right)_T=0.$$

OK.

Now, if we rotate the material quickly, then the uneven pressurization will produce uneven heating. In the extreme **adiabatic** case, the resulting temperature gradient $\left(\frac{dT}{dz}\right)_S$ persists for a while. (We replace the condition of constant temperature with one of constant entropy to represent the lack of heat transfer.)

Let's evaluate this gradient:

$$\left(\frac{dT}{dz}\right)_S=\left(\frac{dT}{dP}\right)_S\left(\frac{dP}{dz}\right)_S=\left(\frac{dV}{dS}\right)_P\rho g=\left(\frac{dV}{dT}\right)_P\left(\frac{dT}{dS}\right)_P\rho g=\frac{\alpha TV\rho g}{C_P}=\frac{\alpha Tg}{c_P},$$

where we've used the chain rule, a Maxwell relation, the chain rule again, and the definitions of the thermal expansion coefficient $\alpha$, the constant-pressure heat capacity $C_P$, and the constant-pressure specific heat $c_P$.

Notably, the same temperature gradient arises if a column contains a fluid and regions tend to rise and fall; this is called the [lapse rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapse_rate). If the fluid is an ideal gas, then $\alpha=T^{-1}$, and we have $$\frac{dT}{dz}=\frac{g}{c_P},$$ where $c_P$ is the constant-pressure specific heat. For air, the lapse rate is about 10°C/km.

A useful nondimensional number to evaluate just how fast regions rise and fall is the [Rayleigh number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_number); larger values indicate that convection dominates over conduction. The Rayleigh number is typically far greater than unity in the atmosphere, which is why the lapse rate is relevant.

You asked about ice. Ice has a Rayleigh number of essentially zero because of its solid state, and so the lapse rate is negligible due to the essential lack of convection. However, if you quickly rotate a length of ice upright, the resulting adiabatic temperature gradient in the column is predicted to be $\frac{\alpha Tg}{c_P}$, as calculated above. This is around 0.06°C/km around the freezing point (ignoring any pressure-induced melting), quite a bit smaller than that of air because of the lower thermal expansion coefficient and the higher specific heat.